# Why does this js code only change the last div?

Tags: javascript, html, class

The button should replace all the letters (a, b, c) with 'test', but it only replaces the last (c).

If I replace the line of code inside of updateHTML() with the commented line, the code works as intended. Can someone explain what the difference is and why the lines of code work differently.

My js and html files:

```js
let names = ["a", "b", "c"];
let objs = [];
let container;
let form;

class Class {
   constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.buildHTML();
   }

   buildHTML() {
      container.innerHTML += `
        <div id="${this.name}">
            ${this.name}
        </div>`
      this.inner_container = document.getElementById(this.name);
   }

   updateHTML() {
      this.inner_container.innerHTML = "test";
      // document.getElementById(this.name).innerHTML = "test";
   }
}

function main() {
   container = document.getElementById("container");

   for (var name in names) {
      objs.push(new Class(names[name]));
   }

   form = document.getElementById("form");
   form.addEventListener('submit', eventHandler_submit_form);
}

function eventHandler_submit_form(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   for (var obj in objs) {
      objs[obj].updateHTML();
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sample Text</title>
</head>

<body onload="main()">
    <form id="form">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `container.innerHTML += ...` will *clobber* your HTML, stripping anything that isn't directly stored in the HTML itself, including event handlers and in this case element references. Use `container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "...")` instead.

Comment: `updateHTML() { this.inner_container.innerHTML = "test";` is only going to update the object and not change the rendered HTML, is that intentional?

Comment: Also, don't use `for...in` loops on arrays, it offers no guarantee of iteration order and iterates all enumerable properties which may include unexpected keys. Use `for...of` instead.

Comment: @coll that's not completey accurate, had the OP not overwritten the DOM references as noted by Niet the Dark Absol the updates would be reflected in the DOM